# Use boolean key from class in widget | Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

First things first I wanna mention that I'm relatively nooby at using keys and classes to make the code cleaner. I just started with this project and I'm thankful about all information you can add to the answer of my question.

I have following class:

```
class SideMenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideMenuItem({
    Key? key,
    this.isActive,
    this.isHover = false,
    this.itemCount,
    this.showBorder = true,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool? isActive, isHover, showBorder;
  final int? itemCount;
  final Icon? icon;
  final String? title;
  final VoidCallback? press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  Row(
    children: [
      icon!,
      const SizedBox(width: kDefaultPadding * 0.75),
      Text(
        title!,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(
              color: (isActive! || isHover!)
                  ? kTextColor
                  : kGrayColor,
                 ),
       ),
       const Spacer(),
     ],
   ),
  ...
}
```

And this widget I wanna make use of isActive and isHovered as well:

```
            SideMenuItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.inbox, size: 20, color: (isActive || isHover) ? kPrimaryColor : kGrayColor,),
                title: "Bestellungen",
                press: () {})
```

But as you might now I can't use the both variables in the other widget. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`style` can receive null if it can't find  `Theme.of(context).textTheme.button`.

To have hovered effect, you can wrap `SideMenuItem` with `InkWell` by providing its `hoverColor`  or making it transparent and using `onHover` callback.

```dart
//state level
bool isHover = false;  
bool isActive = false;
 ....

InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
    onHover: (value) {
      setState(() {
        isHover = value;
      });
    },
    child: SideMenuItem(
      title: "Bestellungen",
      isActive: isActive,
      isHover: isHover,
    ),
  ),
```